# How to observe LiveData changes from a Room Database using Data Binding Library

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding

First time implementing Room and Data Binding.

In my `ViewModel`:

```
var numberOfClubs = ObservableInt(0)
private var clubs: LiveData<List<Club>> = clubDao.getAllClubs()
```

I then try to get `clubs.value` after inserting into the Room database but am getting a `KotlinNullPointerException` every time.

```
fun addClubs() {
    Observable.fromCallable({
        clubDao.insertClubs(listOf(Club(null, "clubName"))
    })
        .subscribeOn(schedulerFacade.computation)
        .subscribe(
            {
                numberOfClubs.set(clubs.value!!.size) <--- Kotlin NPE
            },
            { error ->
                logWrapper.e("MainViewModel", error.message!!)
                clubError.set(true)
            })
}
```

In my XML I'm calling: `android:text="@{viewModel.numberOfClubs}"`.

As inserting into the Room database doesn't cause anything to be returned, I can't set `numberOfClubs` with the result. I assumed that `clubs` should track the changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a bit of a `LiveData` misunderstanding from myself. In order to get a `LiveData` object to begin emitting things is to [`.observe()`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.html#observe_livedata_objects) it. As `LiveData` is lifecycle aware, [`.observe()`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.html#observe_livedata_objects) is best called from within a `Fragment` or `Activity` as it has a reference to [`LifecycleOwner`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LifecycleOwner.html) which must be the first parameter passed into `.observe()`.

I'm perhaps not following best practices as I set an `ObservableInt` in the `ViewModel` from my `Activity` but I used:

```
viewModel.clubs
    .observe(this, Observer { clubs ->
        viewModel.numberOfClubs.set(clubs!!.size)
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as you figured out already LiveData is lifecycle aware. That means that it observe aslong as the livecycle owner is present.

Even if you've posted the solution already, you shouldnt use !! at all.

```
viewModel.clubs.observe(this, {
    it?.let { 
       viewModel.numberOfClubs.set(it.size)
    }
)
```

is the proper way doing a null check before assigning the size of your recieved list.

By the way, if you want to get the items size in your layout, you should use

```
text="@{viewModel.clubsList.size() + ``}"
```

and observe a list, not a list size using

```
val clubsList = ObservableArrayList<..>() 

viewModel.clubs.observe(this, {
    it?.let { 
       viewModel.clubsList.set(it)
    }
)
```

Comment: Much appreciated for the added comments :)